# How to do basic authentication for the Request in WEBLoad Radview performance tool

Tags: webloadui

How to do basic authentication for the request in web load performance tool?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the right thing, but need to change the order - move the Password and username settings above the wlHttp.Post command.

Answer (score 1):

Add before calling the post command

```js
//StartAuthentication
wlHttp.OverrideAuthorizationHeader = true;
wlHttp.Header["Authorization"] = "Basic XXXXXX";
//EndAuthentication
```

Comment: This will work too but you'll need to manually generate the authorization data (user name : password as Base64), normally you would only use that option for custom authentication, like 'Bearer' authentication. For basic authentication specifying username/password is simpler.